# Prove that the set A satisfies all the axioms to be a commutative ring with unity. Indicate the zero element, the unity and the negative.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> A set $A$ with operation of addition and multiplication is given. Prove
>   that the set $A$ satisfies all the axioms to be a commutative ring with
>   unity. Indicate the zero element, the unity and the negative of an
>   arbitrary $a$.
>
> $A$ is the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of the integers, with the following addition $+$ and multiplication $*$
>
> $a+b=a+b-1$
>
> $a*b=ab-(a+b)+2$

[image]

So above are the axioms.

**For axiom 1:**

We know that the integers $\mathbb{Z}=A$ form an abelian group, therefore A is an abelian group under addition.

**For axiom 2:**

Multiplication of integers is associative.

For $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, $a \times 1=a$ holds.

**For axiom 3:**

Now is the time were we use the above equations.

First, we need to show:

$$ a\times (b+c)=(a \times b)+(a \times c)$$ for all $a,b,c$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

$$b+c=b+c-1$$
$$ a\times (b+c)=a(b+c-1)-(a+b+c-1)+2=ab+ac-a-a-b-c+1+2=ab+ac-2a-b-c+3$$

$$ a\times b=ab-(a+b)+2$$
$$ a \times c=ac-(a+c)+2$$
$$(a \times b)+(a \times c)=(ab-(a+b)+2)+(ac-(a+c)+2)-1=ab-a-b+2+ac-a-c+2-1=ab-2a-b+ac-c+3$$

Therefore, they are equal.

Now, we need to show the second part of axiom 3:

$$(b+c) \times a=(b \times a)+(c \times a)$$ for all $a,b,c$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

$$b+c=b+c-1$$
$$(b+c) \times a=(b+c-1)(a)-(b+c-1+a)+2=ab+ac-a-b-c+1-a+2=ab+ac-2a-b-c+3$$

$$ b \times a=ba-(b+a)+2$$
$$ c \times a=ca-(c+a)+2$$
$$ (b \times a)+(c \times a)=(ba-(b+a)+2)+(ca-(c+a)+2)-1=ba-b-a+2+ca-c-a+2-1=ab-b-2a+ac-c+3$$

which is the same as well. Thus, this is a ring.

Can anyone verify?

Comment: writing $a+b=a+b-1$ should immediately give you a headache. Are you sure the problem was stated like that?

Comment: You should use a different symbol for the "new" sum operation.

Comment: Recommend using \oplus and \otimes ($\oplus \otimes$) for temporary replacements for the "new" symbols (just be aware that they have other meanings in later contexts as well, but they should fit your purposes for now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument for **axiom 1** is not right. We know $\Bbb Z$ is an abelian group, but more precisely, $(\Bbb Z, +)$ is an abelian group, i.e., $\Bbb Z$ is an abelian group with the usual sum as operation. Here you have defined a different operation in $\Bbb Z$ that may lead to an abelian group or not, no matter it's related with the usual sum (for example, I can define $a +' b=a+1$  and $(\Bbb Z,+')$ wouldn't be a group).

Let's denote the "new" sum by $\oplus$. For that item, you must show "by hand" that for all $a,b,c\in \Bbb Z$

$$a\oplus b = b\oplus a, \ \ \ a\oplus (b\oplus c) = (a\oplus b) \oplus c$$

and that there exists some element $0' \in \Bbb Z$ such that $a\oplus 0'= 0'\oplus a=a$ for all $a\in \Bbb Z$ ($0'$ may differ from $0$). You also must check the existence of inverses.

The same goes for **axiom 2** (your work on **axiom 3** is fine, moreover, that idea is the one needed in axiom **1** and **2**).

Comment: I see, I must have misunderstood what the book was saying. I didn't realize it is a different set. When you say 0' may differ from 0, do you mean that the zero element does not have to be 0 but could be another number?

Comment: @Chilanie Those are not different sets, but diferent algebraic structures. About the zero element, you're right, $0'$ maybe a diferent element from $0$, indeed, can you see what number is it? $0'$ must satisfy $a+ 0'-1= a$ for all $a\in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Oh okay. $0'$ is $1$?

Comment: That's right.  Also, $1'$ is not $1$ (otherwise, the ring would have only one element)